# slurm limit number of spwaned processes

Tags: fork, slurm

I am a newbie trying to install/administer slurm. I want to limit the amount of forking a slurm job can do. I used stress command to see the CPU utilization by slurm.

When I run this batch script

```sh
#SBATCH -p Test -c 1
stress -c 1
```

The job runs fine with one core used 100 percent. But this script

```sh
#SBATCH -p Test -c 1
stress -c 20
```

also runs but the top command gives list of 20PIDs forked with cpu utilization of 5 percent each. This makes sense as the total utilization is 1 CPU core 100 percent. This makes load averages go crazy which I learned by googling, are not a correct view of system load. I have 2 questions

1. Is it possible in slurm to limit such a behavior from the admin config by killing the second run. My various attempts have so far yielded nothing. The slurm is configured with cgroup and kills over memory jobs fine. No MPI is used or configured.
2. Does this behavior cause inefficiency because of process waiting times ?

I tried setting these drastic params to check if something happens.

MaxStepCount=1
MaxTasksPerNode=2

But surprisingly nothing happens and I can submit many more jobs after this.

Answer (score 0):

Slurm's job is to allocate computational resources to user jobs. The lowest unit of computation manageable is referred to in the documentation as the CPU. This refers to processing threads/ execution cores, not physical cores. Slurm does not oversee how those resources are managed by the job. So no, nothing in Slurm can kill a job with too many userland threads.

Running that many threads would probably affect efficiency, yes. All those threads will cause increased context switching unless the job has enough cpu threads to handle them.

MaxStepCount and MaxTasksPerNode are for jobs. "Tasks" in this context are not userland threads but separate processes launched by a job step.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question.